# Does ConTeXt have any tool for outputing a plain TXT file of the document?

Tags: context, text, output

I a working with some students who have very very slow Internet, and they struggle even to open a 20 kb file, so I'm sending just a plain text file instead. It does work to copy and paste from the PDF, but for a more efficient workflow, does ConTeXt have any flag to create a plain TXT file instead of a PDF from the TEX file?

Comment: ConTeXt can export to XML/XHTML or you can simply run `pdftotext` on the generated PDF file.

Comment: In addition to Aditya's suggestion, sending the tex file might also be an option. It is probably as readable as some converted output in plain text.

Comment: Pandoc can read ConTeXt and export to plain text (for example `pandoc -f latex -t plain yourcontextfile.tex`). This has the advantage that the conversion is done on the input directly, however some elements are not converted.

Comment: How do you intend to display math with only plain text?

Comment: @Marijn, pandoc has a latex reader but not a context reader. So it cannot convert context files to plain txt

Comment: @Aditya the latex reader also works reasonably well on context (I tried it yesterday), although some elements are not converted.